# When inserting an array with TypeORM, the order of id that comes out as result?

Tags: mysql, node.js, arrays, orm, typeorm

TypeORM is working on inserting arrays using INSERT. 
I'm going to do another task using the IDs that came out as a result of insert. 
At this time, the IDs that come out as a result of insert come out in the order of array when insert?

```
// customRepository.ts
insertArr(nameArr : {name : string}[]){
    reuturn this.createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(customTable)
    .values(nameArr)
    .execute()
}
```

```
// service.ts

        const connection = getConnection();
        const repository = connection.getCustomRepository('customRepository')
        const arr = [{name : 'first'},{name : 'second'}]


        const result =
          await repository.insertArr(
            arr
          );

        console.log('result : ', result);
        //Does this result come out in the order of insert?
```

Thank you!!!